# Matrix by matrix differentiation question

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

$A,B,C$ are matrices, and $C=AB$.
$l$ is a scalar, and $l=f(C)$.

If $\dfrac{\partial l}{\partial C}$ is known, what is $\dfrac{\partial l}{\partial A}$?

Comment: That depends on how you define your scalar-by-matrix derivative. One valid form is $$\operatorname{trace}([\partial l / \partial C]^T B)$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you much, I think I'm looking for the other one that is of the same shape as $A$, and could you please extend it a bit to an answer? thanks!

Comment: Made a mistake there, actually. In any case, I'll post a full answer if I get the chance

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Frobenius Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) to write the differential of the function, then perform a change of variables
$$\eqalign{
dl &= \frac{\partial l}{\partial C}:dC \cr
   &= \frac{\partial l}{\partial C}:dA\,B \cr
   &= \frac{\partial l}{\partial C}\,B^T:dA \cr\cr
\frac{\partial l}{\partial A} &= \frac{\partial l}{\partial C}\,B^T \cr
}$$

Comment: hi, thank you, I feel this is the answer I'n looking for. I'm not quite familiar with matrix differentiation though, could you explain a bit (or give a reference) how $\frac{\partial l}{\partial C}:dAB = \frac{\partial l}{\partial C}\,B^T:dA$?

Comment: You can prove it directly using Einstein-index notation, e.g. $$\eqalign{C:AB &\rightarrow C_{ij}A_{ik}B_{kj} \cr &= C_{ij}B_{kj}A_{ik} \cr &= C_{ij}B^T_{jk}A_{ik} \cr &\rightarrow CB^T:A \cr}$$

Comment: @greg hi, thank you lots, and sorry I've made a mistake actually I'm interested in the differentiation part, how $dC$ becomes $dA B$?

Comment: The differential of a product is simply $$d(AB)=(dA)B+A(dB)$$ since your question is about the gradient with respect to $A$, the matrix $B$ is held constant, so $dB=0$.